# Shopware 6 RuleBuilder: Why is RuleScope's getContext()->getSource() always SalesChannelApiSource, not AdminSalesChannelApiSource in administration?

Tags: shopware6

I want to create a rule in Shopware 6 using the RuleBuilder that checks whether you are in the administration or the storefront.

Inside the RuleScope the context Source in `$scope->getContext()->getSource()`  is always an instance of `SalesChannelApiSource`. I would expect it to be `AdminSalesChannelApiSource` when I am in administration. Is this a bug or is there a config for this?

I want to show some payment methods only in the administration and hide them from the Frontend, of course I could check the request path in request stack, but it would be nice to check it directly in the rule scope.

Answer (score -1):

This is intended behavior. There is no `SalesChannelContext` when using the admin API. For instance, when the status of an order is changed in the administration and a flow is triggered, the `SalesChannelContext` and the therein contained `Context` are re-assembled from the parameters originally persisted with the order. Therefore a state is regained that matches the state when the order was placed. This makes it possible to use rule conditions that target cart line items to also target order line items, as the latter are being converted back to cart line items for the evaluation of rules. In short, rules should always expect a regular `SalesChannelContext` and shouldn't even consider if the rule evaluation was initially triggered through the administration, as there should be no difference. The aforementioned `AdminSalesChannelApiSource` is part of a legacy solution that should not be considered.

Comment: So will the AdminSalesChannelApiSource be removed in the future?

How would you add a rule that checks if the action is called from the administration?
Would you check the request path?

Comment: The class is used only in a very specific case and yes, you shouldn't rely on it at all. It may well be deprecated in the future. If you ask me such a condition to check whether something triggering rule evaluation originated from the admin api shouldn't exist at all. A condition should only consider the available data. That is the cart und the sales channel context. What you could do is check for the scope passed to a condition. An instance of `FlowRuleScope` will always consider an already placed order, usually the consequence of an action from within the administration.